# CSS: iPhone / iPad Safari adds extra margins or padding around elements?

Tags: iphone, css, ipad, safari

The site I am currently working on (roemlunchdinner.nl) looks fine in all major browsers but Safari on the iPhone and the iPad seems to add extra margins or padding around elements on the lower part of the page. I have tried setting the margins and padding to zero on all relevant elements, setting specific widths etc. but to no avail. I cannot reproduce this is any other browser. Anyone here has an idea what is going on here?

I am new here so am not yet allowed to post screenshots. Here are the links to the screenshot I would have liked to post:

[Safari Windows screenshot](http://www.roemlunchdinner.nl/wp-content/uploads/111018-ROEM-Screenshot-Safari-Windows.png)

[Safari iPad screenshot](http://www.roemlunchdinner.nl/wp-content/uploads/111018-ROEM-Screenshot-Safari-iPad.png)

Answer (score 2):

Mobile Safari resizes elements based on its best guess of what's going to be readable for the user.

You can override this behaviour across the entire site by doing this in your CSS:

```
body { -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; }
```

or you can target just individual elements.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it is not a problem with the font-size. Just to be sure I tried it anyway but, as expected, it made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

try using media queries for ipad 
@media only screen and (device-width: 768px) {
 your css...
}

give different width and see. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

add css to element or related class: `padding:0 @important!;`